# How to copy an object between 2 NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

How can I copy an `NSManagedObject` from one `NSManagedObjectContext` to another?

I have 2 different `NSManagedObjectContext`, each with it's own `NSManagedObjectModel` and separate persistent store.  Each of the 2 MOC has an entity called `Observation` that is tied to the same Observation class.

I want to copy objects from one MOC to the other.  Since the objects are of the same class, I would like to just fetch an object from one MOC and save it to the other.  Is this possible, or do I need to insert a new object into the target MOC and then set each property one at a time?

Comment: are you trying to make the content appear in two different views using one MOC? if so then go ahead use same fetchresult controller / moc in both classes it will show up in two views but one moc.

Comment: No, actually copying the objects from one MOC to another MOC, completely independent of any view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **copy** one object and insert a new one into the other managed object context. Most likely you would have to copy the property values over one by one to do this.

*The reason is that all these objects have opaque unique ID, so you cannot just take it from one context to the other.*

Comment: Does this mean I should copy all properties, but NOT the id?

Comment: Unless it is your own id-like property. Do *not* copy the ObjectID.